# Set hostname in GraphQL server

Tags: prisma-graphql

Would you please let me know how I can set the host name in GraphQLServer (graphql-yoga)? I want to set the hostname to my domain name (which is located on a Ubuntu server) and use it instead of "localhost", but unfortunately it doesn’t work.

I used the following code:

```
    const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')
    const { Prisma } = require('prisma-binding')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    ...

    const db = new Prisma({
      typeDefs: process.env.PRISMA_TYPE_DEFS,
      endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT,
    })

    const server = new GraphQLServer({
      typeDefs: process.env.QRAPHQL_TYPE_DEFS,
      resolvers,
      directiveResolvers,
      context: req => ({
        ...req,
        db
      }),
    })

    server.express.use( bodyParser.json({limit: "500mb"}) );
    server.express.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "500mb", extended: true}) ); 
    server.express.post(
      server.options.endpoint,
      checkJwt,
      (err, req, res, next) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).send(err.message)
        next()
      }
    )
    server.express.post(server.options.endpoint, (req, res, next) =>
      getUser(req, res, next, db)
    )

    const options = {
      port: process.env.PORT,
      hostname: "xxx"
    }
    server.start(options, ({ port }) =>
      console.log(
        `Server started, listening on port ${port} for incoming requests.`,
      ),
    )
```

I want to set the hostname to my domain name and use it instead of "localhost", but unfortunately it doesn’t work.

Would you please help me?

Thanks.
David

Comment: Maybe show your [mcve]? It's unclear in what context you want this.

Comment: Hi David, attaching a domain aka hostname to your server intead varies on where are you hosting your server, is it a cloud provider or is it on premise, SAAS etc... , you need to clarify more about how are you hosting your server.